# Firebase and Node.js application results in the requested URL was not found on this server for the firebase serve command

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I have created a Node.js application and trying to deploy in the Firebase for hosting. Before deploying, I am making sure that it will work properly using the command `firebase serve --only hosting,function`. This command creates the server and I am able to access the Home page of the application using the URL (localhost:5000) provided by Firebase but for some reason, my `Angularjs` HTTP request is unable to find the `Node.js` controller due to which I am getting the `404 URL not found error` in the brwoser.

As soon as the `index.html` is accessed using the `localhost:5000` I am trying to populate various dropdown options in my frontend. These options are present within the Node.js controller file `populator.js`. Hence I am making an HTTP request from `angularjs` to my `node.js` controller but I get the `404 URL not found error`. I am guessing there is some issue with folder structure or the `firebase.json` file due to which the code is unable to find my `Node.js` controller.

My `firebase.json` file:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My `index.js` file:

```
const   functions                   =   require("firebase-functions");
const   express                     =   require('express');
const   app                         =   express();

//call function to popultae the fields
app.get('/populateFields', function(req,res){
    populateFields.BusinessStep(function(data){
        res.send(data);
    });
});

exports.app      =   functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Here is my folder structure

```
Firebase Hosting (root)
    |--functions
        |---index.js
        |---package.json
    |
    --public
        |---index.html
    |
    --firebase.json
    --.firebaserc
```

I tried running the command `firebase serve --only hosting,function` in both the root directory and within the `functions` folder but none worked and still getting the error `The requested URL was not found on this server.`

I found many post related to this issue but could not find there solution after trying the methods mentioned there hence posting this question.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail what isn't working the way you expect.  Be sure to include enough information so that anyone can reproduce the issue and observe what you are observing.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for the response. I have edited the question. I hope its now understandable clearly.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by running following command `firebase serve --only functions,hosting`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running the command wrongly so I was getting that issue the actual command is

`firebase serve --only functions,hosting`

If anyone is facing the issue then run the command correctly.

Comment: The order shouldn't matter.  If you have clear proof that the order does matter, file an issue with your reproduction steps on GitHub and the team will take a look.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: I was facing this problem. It solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

"I was running the command wrongly so I was getting that issue the actual command is
firebase serve --only functions,hosting"
I guess that the error was for specifying `function` instead of `functions`